# Kubernetes Ingress Configuration are not updated on GKE cluster?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I want to update the ingress configuration and which will apply on ingress instance running on kuberntes cluter on gcloud.

For this I have performed two steps:

1. Firstly, people ask that set both annotation in `ingress.yml` and then re-create ingress will solve the issue mentioned on [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/21#issuecomment-408618569).

> ```
> kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 20m
> ```

After deleting the ingress from cluster and create the ingress again
    also declared me unlucky.

**ingress.yml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 20m
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "20m"
```

2. Secondly, configure the ConfigMap file on the gcloul cluster, so that our ingress configuration will update, but come up with the negative result mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347770/nginx-ingress-kubernetes-io-proxy-body-size-not-working).

**nginx-config.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: default
data:
  proxy-body-size: "20m"
```

So how can I update my ingress properties such as annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size`, so that I can upload data more than 1 MB (where my cluster deployed on GKE)?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the annotations part in your `Ingress` resource. Let me elaborate on that.

The problem is that you trying to use [GCE controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) and apply annotations specifically for [NGINX Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx).  You cannot use NGINX Ingress controller annotations with GCE controller.

For your configuration to work you would need to deploy NGINX Ingress controller.

You can deploy it by following [official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

After deploying NGINX Ingress controller the part of the `Ingress` definition should look like that:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "20m"
```

Take a specific look at part below:

```
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "20m"
```

Please refer to official [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/) when applying annotations for NGINX Ingress controller.

Comment: Thank you @Dawid for your help.

Comment: Hi @Dawid Kruk, I want to do the same for 'gce' type ingress controller, how can I achieve this? Tried many ways, but couldn't able to find the annotation for that.

Refer: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#creating_an_ingress

Comment: I haven’t checked that extensively but If you couldn’t find it I’m afraid that this is not supported. You can create a feature request for it on gke issue tracker. Is there a specific feature of gke ingress that you want to use?